# Vue 3: Rendering the object in descending order issue

Tags: vue.js, sorting

I am trying to render the data in the `desc` order, but vue 3 always render it in the `asc` order

```js
state: {
    entries: {
        2022: {
            10: {...},
            11: {...},
            12: {...},
            ...
        },
        2021: {
            10: {...},
            12: {...},
            ...
        },
        2020: {
            3: {...},
            8: {...},
            ...
        },
    },
}
```

But it always renders like this `2020, 2021, 2022` where as I require it to be `2022, 2021, 2020`,

[image]

How to fix it

Comment: First of all, you generally shouldn't rely on the order of object keys. This is what arrays are for. And incidentally, arrays are easier to sort because of `sort` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> integers are iterated first in the ascending order

Small Demo demonstrating above statement.

```js
var jsonObj = {
  3: 'March',
  1: 'Jan',
  5: 'May'
};

console.log(jsonObj);
```

That's what a JavaScript engine recognizes as an integer and what humans recognize as a number are not same.

To achieve the order, we can convert that object into an array.

**Demo :**

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      list: [{
      3: 'March' }, {
      1: 'Jan' }, {
      5: 'May' }]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.0/vue.js"></script>

<body>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in list" :key="index">
        {{ item[Object.keys(item)[0]] }}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```